# Однородные обособленные обороты, соединенные парными союзами

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему ставится запятая перед первой частью союза *"если не...то"*, если есть правило, согласно которому запятая в парном союзе (*не только...но и, как...так и, не столько...сколько и др.*) ставится только перед второй его частью.

Но ведь все эти люди получили первоначальное образование, если не довольно глубокое, то довольно многостороннее. (В. Г. Белинский)

Это зависит от основного правила - обособления прилагательных с зависимым словами или от пояснительного значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По смыслу фразы я бы эту запятую не ставила. Решила посмотреть источник, на 4 сайтах её нет:

> Так называемый наш «словесник» с презрением смотрит на математику,
>   которая не далась ему в школе. Скажут: все это не дух разъединения, а
>   дух полупросвещения или полуобразованности. Так! но ведь все эти люди
>   получили первоначальное образование если не довольно глубокое, то
>   довольно многостороннее: словесник учился еще в школе математике, а
>   математик — словесности.

https://lektsia.com/5x78f4.html

https://libking.ru/books/prose-/prose-classic/282865-vissarion-belinskiy-mysli-i-zametki-o-russkoy-literature.html

https://libcat.ru/knigi/proza/klassicheskaya-proza/258770-vissarion-belinskij-mysli-i-zametki-o-russkoj-literature.html

http://az.lib.ru/b/belinskij_w_g/text_0060.shtml Последняя ссылка -  В. Г. Белинский. Собрание сочинений в трех томах под общей редакцией Ф. М. Головенченко    ОГИЗ, ГИХЛ, М., 1948. Том III. Статьи и рецензии 1843-1848
   Редакция В. И. Кулешова. Мне кажется, этому изданию стоит верить. Только на одном сайте встретила с запятой, скорее всего, сайт из новых, у меня к нему меньше доверия. Как объяснить? Видимо, они сочли пояснением, но смысл ведь не в том, что словесник и математик получили какое-то первоначальное образование, а в том, что оно достаточно глубокое или хотя бы многостороннее, ведь это интеллигенция. Здесь определение тесно связано со сказуемым - запятая не нужна. Корректоры или тот, кто набирал текст, исказили авторскую мысль.